# Jooq: jsonb fetchInto custom type

Tags: java, jooq

what's the correct way to map jsonb record into custom data type?
just like normal table fields.

```sql
create table t_order
(
    id    serial
        constraint t_order_pk
            primary key,
    key   varchar(255) not null,
    value jsonb        not null
);

create unique index t_order_id_uindex
    on t_order (id);

create index t_order_value_index
    on t_order using gin (value);
```

```java
@Data
@Builder
class Order {

  private List<OrderItem> orderItems;

  @Data
  @Builder
  public static class OrderItem {

    private BigDecimal price;
    private BigDecimal quantity;
  }
}
```

```java
@Test
  void findOrderById() {
    var order =
        dsl.select(T_ORDER.VALUE)
            .from(T_ORDER)
            .where(T_ORDER.ID.eq(1))
            .fetchOptionalInto(Order.class); // OOPS!
    assertTrue(order.isPresent());
    log.info(order);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) on your classpath, jOOQ's [`DefaultConverterProvider`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/converter-provider/) will automatically use those to map your `JSONB` content to your data, so that should be all you need to do to make this work.